# How to stop JVM core dump with Java Spark Parquet writing

Tags: java, apache-spark

Running into a problem with Spark, trying to create a Dataset by 'hand' and then write it out to parquet. I've dumbed down this example so you can see whats going on.

I have two classes (they come from a library so its not easy to change them)

```
public class RawSearch implements Serializable {

    protected long timestamp;

    @Nullable
    protected List<RawItinerary> itineraries;

}

public class RawItinerary implements Serializable {

    protected long timestamp;

    @Nullable
    protected String originCityCode;

    @Nullable
    protected String destinationCityCode;

    protected int departDate;
    protected int returnDate;
    protected String currencyCode;

    protected double totalAmount;
    protected double totalTaxAmount;
    protected double totalSurchargeAmount;

    @Nullable
    protected String validatingCarrier;

    protected boolean multiCarrier;

    @Nullable
    protected String cabin;

    public boolean isPrivate() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If I attempt to create a RawSearch with a RawItinerary and write to parquet, the JVM core dumps

```
       List<RawSearch> searches = new ArrayList<>();

        RawSearch rawSearch = new RawSearch();

        rawSearch.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        rawSearch.setItineraries(new ArrayList<>());
        searches.add(rawSearch);

        RawItinerary itinerary = new RawItinerary();

        itinerary.setCabin("Coach");
        itinerary.setCurrencyCode("USD");
        itinerary.setDepartDate(20200215);
        itinerary.setDestinationCityCode("EDI");
        itinerary.setMultiCarrier(false);
        itinerary.setOriginCityCode("LON");
        itinerary.setReturnDate(0);
        itinerary.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        itinerary.setValidatingCarrier("BA");

        rawSearch.getItineraries().add(itinerary);

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Bob").master("local[1]").getOrCreate();

        Dataset<RawSearch> searchDataset = sparkSession.createDataset(searches, Encoders.bean(RawSearch.class));

        searchDataset.write()
                .parquet("/Users/graemewallace/Downloads/bob-" + System.currentTimeMillis());

        sparkSession.close();
```

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x0000000109adccda, pid=56878, tid=0x0000000000008903
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_241-b07) (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.241-b07 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0xdccda]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

If i get rid of some of the members from RawItinerary - it starts working. If i get rid of the isPrivate() method, it starts working.

Anyone got a clue whats going on here ?

Comment: I ended up having to change the RawItinerary class definition to change the isPrivate() method to something not bean like. Once that was done, everything worked.

Comment: may be because Encoders.bean couldn't create an encoder for isPrivate?